# Pass data from parent to child component in react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass some data from a parents container to a child, but react doesn't render the data to be passed. Instead, the output on the 'p' tag is blank. What am I doing wrong?

Parent container:

```
//import Child from ...
class Parent extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
          text: "DUMMY TEXT"
       }
   }

   render() {
      return(
         <Child data={this.state.text} />
      );
   }
}
```

Child component:

```
class Child extends Component {
   render() {
      return(
         <p>{this.props.data}</p>
      );
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? [It works for me](https://codesandbox.io/s/n3rl6n9nnm).

Comment: Agree with @Tholle [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/262193/)

Comment: After debugging, I realized that I was calling the 'Child' component in multiple places @Tholle

Comment: Alright, great. So you could resolve the error?